# dataframe fill in next row with previous row value

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

```
AMA1=close1
AMA(t)=AMA(t-1)+alpha(t)*(close(t)-AMA(t-1))

id    date        close   alpha     AMA
1  2016-01-04      343      1       343
2  2016-01-05      335      2       327  (343+2*(335-343))
3  2016-01-06      337      3       357  (327+3*(337-327))
4  2016-01-07      338     -1       376  (357-1*(338-357))
```

I want to calculate column AMA of a dataframe, the rule likes this:

```
if id==1, AMA(1)=close(1)
if id>1,  AMA(t)=AMA(t-1)+alpha(t)*(close(t)-AMA(t-1))
```

I used for loop, but it's very slow when i'm dealing with large data.
Does anyone know how to do this without for loop?Many thanks!!

```
for i in range(len(df)):
   if i==1:
      AMA(1)=close(1)
   if i>1:
      AMA(t)=AMA(t-1)+alpha(t)*(close(t)-AMA(t-1))
```

Comment: `df['close'].iloc[0] + df['random'].cumsum()`

Comment: @user3483203 thanks for your help. maybe my example is not a good one, i want find a faster way,not using for loop

Comment: The code I posted doesn't use an explicit loop..

Comment: i updated a new example, this example can better explain my question @user3483203